# Weird issue, attribute value in catalog_product_entity_text but empty when I do an export

Tags: magento-1.9

Very strange issue, when I open a product I can see the value of my attribute (EAN), the value is also in the catalog_product_entity_text table.

[image]

But when I do an export I get this result

"sku","ean"
"002",""

The issue is getting more weird every second. What I now found out is that the field EAN is a textarea field, but when he hits the flat table it becomes a int(11) and he adds the max int 2147483647 in that field for every SKU

Comment: Did you create the attribute programmatically or via the backend ?

Comment: Hmm I used a migration tool so I would say programmatically :-) The issue is getting more weird every second. What I now found out is that the field EAN is a textarea field, but when he hits the flat table it becomes a int(11) and he adds the max int 2147483647 in that field for every SKU

Comment: Could you try creating the same attribute with a different name and see if it happens for this new attribute as well? If it doesn't I reckon something got wrong using the migration.

Comment: You are right a new attrbute works fine. Weird, then I have to find a way to get the old data and import it to the new attribute. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magento stores textarea attributes as text not as varchar.

You can get the details by looking at the app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity.php and see the getBackendTypeByInput function:

```
public function getBackendTypeByInput($type)
{
    $field = null;
    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
        case 'gallery':
        case 'media_image':
        case 'multiselect':
            $field = 'varchar';
            break;

        case 'image':
        case 'textarea':
            $field = 'text';
            break;

        case 'date':
            $field = 'datetime';
            break;

        case 'select':
        case 'boolean':
            $field = 'int';
            break;

        case 'price':
            $field = 'decimal';
            break;
    }

    return $field;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question because the whole varchar was a bit stupid what I posted.